# What is the difference between radii of Gyration and hydrodynamic radii of a polymer?

Tags: physical-chemistry, polymers

Why do you consider that the relationship between RH and RG should depend on the quality of the solvent?

Comment: Please post your thoughts regarding the answer- the site has a policy regarding "homework"-type questions which requires you show your effort to solve the problem.